# Take an array of objects and turn into array of strings?

Tags: java, android, arrays

I am trying to convert an array of objects into an array of strings inside a for loop.

I am extracting a property from the object the `title` inside the loop I have several `title` strings, now I want to pass that into a new array?

```
JSONArray shots = response.getJSONArray("shots");
for (int i=0; i < shots.length(); i++) {

    // play with data
    JSONObject post = shots.getJSONObject(i);
    String title = post.getString("title");

    // turn title into an array of strings??

}
```

**EDIT:**

I tried this

```
String[] mStrings = new String[15];

JSONArray shots = response.getJSONArray("shots");
for (int i=0; i < shots.length(); i++) {

    // play with data
    JSONObject post = shots.getJSONObject(i);
    String title = post.getString("title");
    //Log.d("this is my array", "arr: " + title);

    mStrings[i] = title;

}

Log.d("this is my array", "arr: " + mStrings);
```

the result of `Log.d` was `D/this is my array﹕ arr: [Ljava.lang.String;@4294e620`

Comment: It looks like you've done it.  You've stored each title as an element of a String array.  What am I not understanding here?

Comment: It failed to show me in the log basically. So I was unsure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly: you want to get an array with all the titles from the JSON shots ?

```
JSONArray shots = response.getJSONArray("shots");
String titles[] = new String[shots.length()];
for (int i=0; i < shots.length(); i++) {
    JSONObject post = shots.getJSONObject(i);
    String title = post.getString("title");

    titles[i] = title;
}
```

Using a stream you could write:

```
import java.util.stream.IntStream;

JSONArray shots = response.getJSONArray("shots");
String titles[] = IntStream
    .range(0, shots.length())
    .mapToObj(i -> shots.getJSONObject(i))
    .map(post -> post.getString("title"))
    .toArray(String[]::new);
}
```

If you are using this [`JSONArray`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/json/JsonArray.html), you can even write:

```
JSONArray shots = response.getJSONArray("shots");
String titles[] = shots.stream()
    .map(post -> ((JsonObject) post).getString("title"))
    .toArray(String[]::new);
```

Answer (score 1):

The best way to accomplish this is to create a new `ArrayList` that you can store each `String` into as you parse it from the `JSONObject`.

```
ArrayList<String> stringList = new ArrayList<String>();

JSONArray shots = response.getJSONArray("shots");
for (int i=0; i < shots.length(); i++) {

    JSONObject post = shots.getJSONObject(i);
    String title = post.getString("title");

    stringList.add(title);

}
```

Comment: Yeah but what if I want to access the array outside the loop?

Comment: Can I just call stringList? ultimately I want to pass it into an adapter

Comment: Yes, because stringList is instantiated outside of the loop you will be able to use it in a larger scope. Once you have finished parsing through each JSONObject you will have filled the the list with strings and can simply pass the stringList object to your adapter.

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean create an entry in a String array for each title?

If so:

```
JSONArray shots = response.getJSONArray("shots");

List<String> titles = new ArrayList<String>();

for (int i=0; i < shots.length(); i++) {

    // play with data
    JSONObject post = shots.getJSONObject(i);
    String title = post.getString("title");
    titles.add(title)

    // turn title into an array of strings??

}

String[] titleArr = new String[titles.size()];
titleArr = titles.toArray(titleArr);
```

If that's not what you're looking for, please provide some more detail in the question.

Comment: Okay I am trying to create an array to pass into an Adapter so I can have a listView

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
Log.d("this is my array", "arr: " + Arrays.toString(mStrings));
```

instread of

```
Log.d("this is my array", "arr: " + mStrings);
```